# IE11 flexbox text doesn't wrap in list item

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm confronted with the issue of IE11 that the text doesn't wrap as in other browsers. I've set up a codepen with the issue.

https://codepen.io/johnny_gruber/pen/QmBePd

The HTML

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Coca-Cola_logo.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="search">
      search
  </div>
  <div class="language">
      DE v
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Product & Solutions</li>
      <li>Industries</li>
      <li>Facilities</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
      <li>Group Website</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="login">
    login v
  </div>
</header>
```

The css

```
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.logo,
.search,
.language,
.login {
  flex-shrink: 0; 
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
}

li {
  padding: 25px 15px;
}

nav {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

In chrome you can see the expected behaviour. The text wraps if possible. In IE11 it just stays on one line. Is there a chance to get the same behaviour on IE11?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IE 11 requires a unit to be added to the third argument, the flex-basis property

c/o [CanIuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

From there , just set the `ul` to `display:flex` and the `li` to say:

```
li {
  padding: 25px 15px;
  flex: 1 1 50px;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  height: 72px;
}

.search,
.language,
.login {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.logo,
.search,
.language,
.login {
  flex-shrink: 0; 
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  padding: 25px 15px;
  flex: 1 1 50px;
}

nav {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Coca-Cola_logo.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="search">
      search
  </div>
  <div class="language">
      DE v
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Product & Solutions</li>
      <li>Industries</li>
      <li>Facilities</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
      <li>Group Website</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="login">
    login v
  </div>
</header>
```

[**Codepen.io Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JLaYmW)

Comment: Hi 

yes I had this solution already, but the problem is, that the list item now strech over the whole area instead of staying at the right end if the screen is larger.